# How to hide side navigation of Identity in .net core mvc 6 c#

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

Take a look
[image]

I want to hide **Email** and **Two-factor Authentication**.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The side navigation of Identity is defined in _ManageNav.cshtml.If you want want to hide Email and Two-factor Authentication,you can change _ManageNav.cshtml.

Project structure:

[image]

_ManageNav.cshtml:

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@{
var hasExternalLogins = (await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).Any();
}
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.IndexNavClass(ViewContext)" id="profile" asp-page="./Index">Profile</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.EmailNavClass(ViewContext)" id="email" asp-page="./Email">Email</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.ChangePasswordNavClass(ViewContext)" id="change-password" asp-page="./ChangePassword">Password</a></li>
@if (hasExternalLogins)
{
<li id="external-logins" class="nav-item"><a id="external-login" class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.ExternalLoginsNavClass(ViewContext)" asp-page="./ExternalLogins">External logins</a></li>
}
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.TwoFactorAuthenticationNavClass(ViewContext)" id="two-factor" asp-page="./TwoFactorAuthentication">Two-factor authentication</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.PersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext)" id="personal-data" asp-page="./PersonalData">Personal data</a></li>
</ul>
```